# How to create a seperate navigation Drawer for different users : React navigation v5

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-firebase

AdminDrawer => Account, Dashboard, logout

UserDrawer => Profile, Contact, login

1. when user successfully login from firebase it will show "Admin Drawer"
2. when not login from firebase it will show "User Drawer"
   like "foodpanda drawer"

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the same drawer but we will detect variable check user signed in

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        {isSignedIn ? (
          <>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Account" component={Account} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="logout" component={logout} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={SignInScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Contact" component={SignUpScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          </>
        )}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

with isSignedIn is prop pass by redux or context. It's up to you

Two documents helpful for you

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Comment: how can  i connect it with firebase   and how signed in prop handled by redux can you provide  some futher detail .Anh Devit

Comment: This is an example for authentication with firebase https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage
Like my answer https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/ you can flow with that to understand and then try with redux

Comment: I want to change drawer items not screen with in the same drawer like below <DrawerItem
        label="DashboardScreen"
        labelStyle={{marginLeft:-18}}
        onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate('DashboardScreen')}
        icon={()=><Feather name='compass' size={16}  color='#F60875' style={{marginLeft:5}}/>}
      />

Comment: I have a lot of files which I cannot share here I want drawer like "food panda "  if you have any example or link so I can understand it

Comment: Did you view 2 links above?

Comment: yeah but i dont understand them

Comment: this is a document so why you don't try?

Comment: I am using expo